# Is it possible to store multiple values in one column from stored procedure that will be stored as HashSet in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table `MainProperty` modeled in C# with a one-to-many relationship with another table, like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<ForeignProperty> ForeignProperty { get; set; }
```

A stored procedure is called that returns a `List<MainProperty>`, but we're not populating the `ForeignProperty` on any of those records.

In that procedure, the two tables, `MainProperty` and `ForeignProperty` are joined, but nothing is done with that join.

Is there a way in SQL to return a record with it's `ForeignProperty` values in that record so that the model is populated properly in C#?

The issue is that a record could have more than 1 `ForeignProperty` values, and I'm not sure how to property store the multiple values in one column (user-defined table maybe?), and then turn that column of values into an `ICollection` in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way in SQL to return a record with it's ForeignProperty values in that record so that the model is populated properly in C#?

No.  You'll have to fetch the ForeignProperty objects in a subsequent query.  EF will "fix up" the relationships when you do.  Alternatively you can use Lazy Loading and load each `ICollection<ForeignProperty>` on demand.

Comment: So if I have the two ICollections returned from the two queries, will the first have it's HashSet of ForeignProperty values "Fixed up" by EF because of the second query or do I need to do that explicitly to be able to access the ForeignProperty values of a specific MainProperty item?